# Detecting invalid UTF-8 characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

I've already posted several similar questions and I apologize for that, but still have not found a solution.

I have a database where some entries are not legal UTF-8. If I know which entries are not, I can convert them to UTF-8. My version of JavaScript has a method to do that. And this function also seems to work:

```
function utf8_encode(str) {
    return unescape( encodeURIComponent( string ) );
}
```

However, if the text is already UTF-8 the above function will break the already valid UTF-8 characters. You shouldn't convert UTF-8 to UTF-8.

So my problem has come down to this: How can I take a string in JavaScript and determine if the string is valid UTF-8 or not?

An example of such a string might be:

André Blavó MÜCHEN

which got entered in ISO-8859-1 and looks fine when the browser views it as ISO-8859-1 but if the browser is forced to view in UTF-8 it looks like there are invalid characters in the string.

My version of JavaScript also has a ByteBuffer() type so I can handle the bytes in a string one byte at a time easily, if necessary.

Any advice would be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

doug

Update Feb 28, 2014:

I came up with this, but it is insufficient. It catches many non-UTF-8 characters. But is many cases it thinks the text is valid when it isn't. I'm stuck. Anybody have any ideas?

```
function stringIsValidUtf8 (text) {
    if (typeof(text)==="object"){
        for (key in text){
            text[key]=this.toUTF8(text[key]);
        }
    }
    else if (typeof(text) ==="string"){
        var max = text.length;

        for (var i=0; i< max; i++){

            var c1 = text.charAt(i);
            if (c1 >= "\xc0"){
                var c2 = i+1>=max? "\x00" : text[i+1];
                var c3 = i+2 >= max? "\x00" : text[i+2];
                var c4 = i+3 >= max? "\x00" : text[i+3];

                if (c1>= "\xc0" & c1 <="\xdf"){
                    if (c2 >= "\x80" && c2 <= "\xbf"){
                        i++
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                else if (c1 >= "\xe0" & c1 <= "\xef"){
                    if (c2>= "x80" && c2 <= "\xbf" && c3 >= "\x80" && c3 <="\xbf"){
                        i=i+2; 
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                else if (c1>= "\xf0" & c1 <="\xf7"){
                    if (c2>= "\x80" && c2 <="\xbf" && c3 >= "\x80" && c3 <="\xbf" && c4 >= "\x80" && c4 <= "\xbf"){
                        i=i+2;
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                else{
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else if ((c1 & "\xc0") === "\x80"){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you're using php or asp to get the data from database, right? I think the solution will need server-side code because a simple string got no metadata to detect encoding, unless you're thinking about a "semantical" approach to detect encoding...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is entirely server-side JavaScript. The server-side JavaScript accesses the NoSQL, object-oriented database directly and then I use the JavaScript to build the XML. So I am looking for, hoping for, some solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a Node.js \`Buffer\` contains valid UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75108373/how-to-check-if-a-node-js-buffer-contains-valid-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

## UTF-8 validation

### In any Javascript environment in general,

you `try`

```
(new TextDecoder("UTF-8", {fatal: true})).decode(…)
```

and see if it doesn’t throw.

### In Node.js,

you

```
import NodeBuffer, {Buffer} from "node:buffer";
```

and do

```
NodeBuffer.isUtf8(…)
```

.

## UTF-16 validation

And you do

```
"string".isWellFormed()
```

for UTF-16.