# How to check if a Node.js `Buffer` contains valid UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8

I have a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object and I would like to check if all of it is valid UTF-8. Ideally, I would like to get a `string` with said decoded UTF-8 text, too.

I tried [`Buffer.toString`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftostringencoding-start-end) which takes an `encoding` argument which defaults to `utf8`. Unfortunately the docs say this:

> If `encoding` is `'utf8'` and a byte sequence in the input is not valid UTF-8, then each invalid byte is replaced with the replacement character `U+FFFD`.

That's not what I want: I rather want an exception or a boolean flag. Just checking if the resulting string contains `U+FFFD` is not the same as the input text could already have contained `U+FFFD` (just as a valid Unicode codepoint). Of course one could try counting `U+FFFD` in the buffer and the string and then compare, but that seems uselessly complicated and inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import NodeBuffer, {Buffer} from "node:buffer";
```

> ## [`NodeBuffer.isUtf8(input)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufferisutf8input)
>
> - Added in: version 19.4.0, version 18.14.0.
> - `input` (`<Buffer>` | `<ArrayBuffer>` | `<TypedArray>`)
>
> This function returns `true` if input contains only valid UTF-8-encoded data, including the case in which `input` is empty.
>
> Throws if the `input` is a detached array buffer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TextDecoder`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_class_util_textdecoder) from `util`. To get an exception, set the `fatal` flag to `true`.

```
new TextDecoder("utf8", { fatal: true }).decode(buffer)
```

For example:

```
> new TextDecoder("utf8", { fatal: true }).decode(Buffer.from([72, 195, 182, 240, 159, 146, 154, 215, 169, 214, 184, 215, 129]))
'Höשָׁ'

> new TextDecoder("utf8", { fatal: true }).decode(Buffer.from([1, 2, 255, 3, 5]))
Uncaught:
TypeError [ERR_ENCODING_INVALID_ENCODED_DATA]: The encoded data was not valid for encoding utf-8
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:478:5)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at TextDecoder.decode (node:internal/encoding:433:15) {
  errno: 12,
  code: 'ERR_ENCODING_INVALID_ENCODED_DATA'
```